# How to get more BCLK from non-k Corei5 cpu Haswell

Tags: cpu, overclocking, intel-core-i5, haswell

I have a Core I5 4570 Haswell with Cooler Master CPU cooler with Asus Z87-plus Board and Asus ATI 7970 and 8 Gig DDR3 Crucial Ram @ 1600 mhz. I'm Using Windows 8.1 X64.

It’s a Non-K cpu so the multiplier is locked to 36 and the default BCLK is 100 and 102 on turbo. the base clock is 3.4 Ghz and on turbo that'll be 3.6 Ghz.

I want to know how to overclock this non-k CPU to 4 Ghz. I used to do well on these non-k CPUs on Core2Quad versions but this one is so limited but not impossible and unfortunately not many guides on the net are about overclocking non-k Haswells.

Here is what I’ve tried.

1. Disabled IGPU.
2. set the manual DRAM voltage to 1.5.
3. Disabled EPU and other Power Saving Options.
4. Tried to set the Ram Frequency first on 1600 and second on 1333.
5. increased the BCLK to 105.
6. Increased Vcore by 0.200 and it just got my cpu a little bit hot.

With those things done, I could get 3780 Mhz on the CPU and it was stable as I tested it with Aida64 extreme many times but it used to crash once in a while on low CPU usage. How would I be able to get 4 Ghz with this CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't increase BCLK. Increase multiplier. BCLK is about multiple parts of your computer and those parts aren't all designed for overclocking. Just maxout your multiplier and that's all you're going to get fromthat cpu.

[Recommended thread](http://www.overclock.net/t/1101617/bclk)

Comment: "increase multiplier" on a locked CPU, where haswell lacks the multiplier headroom older non-K CPUs had. I would downvote this if I had enough rep, no idea why OP accepted it.

Comment: @ArthurKay locked means you can't go above some predefined multiplier, it doesnt mean you can't change multiplier.

Comment: Haswell took away those usable multipliers though, you are locked to stock w.o. k-series AFAIK.

Comment: @ArthurKay they are adjustable, you just dont see them in bios if you are using a notebook. they are adjusted by windows, and they can be adjusted by using software.